# RecyclerView not displaying item views when I use an actual phone but on emulator it works fine

Tags: java, android

My recyclerView is not displaying the item views and dont no why, and I am able to get the data from the server but the recyclerView is just not populating my data with the ui.

Here is my Adapter class that binds the itemviews with the data :

```
public class AdapterBooking extends           RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>  {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Booking> data= Collections.emptyList();
Booking current ;

public AdapterBooking(Context context,List<Booking> data) {

    this.context = context;
    this.inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.containerbookings, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,  int position) {
    MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
     current = data.get(position);

    myHolder.txtAccommoName.setText(current.AccommoName);
    myHolder.txtBookingDate.setText("Booking Date: " + current.BookingDate);
    myHolder.txtBookingExpiry.setText("Booking Expiry: " + current.BookingDuration);
    myHolder.txtBookngStatus.setText("Status " + current.AccredStatus);
    myHolder.txtBookngStatus.setTextColor( ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

    Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.the_yard_room)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .into(myHolder.img);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

 class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView txtAccommoName;
    ImageView img;
    TextView txtBookingDate;
    TextView txtBookingExpiry;
    TextView txtBookngStatus;
    BootstrapButton btnCancel;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        txtAccommoName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textBookedAccommoName);
        img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageBookedAccomo);
        txtBookingDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBookingDate);
        txtBookingExpiry = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id. txtBookingExpiry);
        txtBookngStatus = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.txtBookingStatus );
        btnCancel   = (BootstrapButton)itemView.findViewById( R.id. btnCancelBookings);

    }
```

Here is my Activity class that gets the data from the server:

```
public class BookingList extends AppCompatActivity {
List<Booking> data;
Booking booking;
RecyclerView recyclerViewBooking;
AdapterBooking mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_booking_list );

    new  Connect().execute();
}


private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    ProgressDialog load;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = null;
    String http = null;

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BookingList.this);
    int studID = settings.getInt("STUDENT_ID_BOOKING",0 );

    public Connect() {

        load = new ProgressDialog(BookingList.this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        load.setMessage("Loading...");
        load.setCancelable(false);
        load.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        http = "http://192.168.42.197:5432/WCF/BookingServices.svc/getAllBookingsByStud/"+studID;
        try {
            url = new URL(http);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "Application/json");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("Response: " + code);
            if(code ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream input =  connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                System.out.println(result.toString());

                return (result.toString());

            }else {
                return("Unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        load.dismiss();
        load.dismiss();
        data= new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Accommodation");
                JSONObject objectStudent = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Student");

                booking = new Booking();

                booking.Name = objectStudent.getString("Name");
                booking.Surname = objectStudent.getString("Surname");
                booking.StudentNumber = objectStudent.getInt("StudentNumber");
                booking.AccommoName = object.getString("AccommoName");
                booking.AccredStatus = object.getString("AccredStatus");
                booking.BookingDate = jsonObject.getString("BookingDate");
                booking.BookingDuration = jsonObject.getString("BookingDuration");
                booking.BookingStatus = jsonObject.getString( "BookingStatus" );

                data.add(booking);
            }

            recyclerViewBooking = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOfbooks);
            mAdapter = new AdapterBooking(BookingList.this,data);
            recyclerViewBooking.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            recyclerViewBooking.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(BookingList.this));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(BookingList.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should extend your adapter `RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterBooking.MyHolder>`

Comment: It will be helpful if you can put a log inside the adapter constructor and print the data size. Is it possible that the JSON array is empty?

Comment: No if the JSON array was empty I will receive a null exception

Comment: @PhulusoRamulifho did you check generic of your adapter?

Comment: @PhulusoRamulifho so you do not have data and it is not emulator/phone difference.

Comment: I think you where right when using the actual phone i get this response: I/System.out: Response: 200 , I/System.out:[]  but when I use an emulator I get I/System.out: Response: 200,  I/System.out: [{"AccommoId"....}]

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
 MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
```

**Instead do this:** *because I think there is no need to get another holder reference when you already have it on onBindViewHolder(..) method*

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,  int position) {

    current = data.get(position);

    holder.txtAccommoName.setText(current.AccommoName);
    holder.txtBookingDate.setText("Booking Date: " + current.BookingDate);
    holder.txtBookingExpiry.setText("Booking Expiry: " + current.BookingDuration);
    holder.txtBookngStatus.setText("Status " + current.AccredStatus);
    holder.txtBookngStatus.setTextColor( ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

    Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.the_yard_room)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .into(holder.img);
}
```

Try this please and do let me know if it changes anything for you.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @adnbsr as well in his comments you need to check this as well because it feels wrong instead you should have done this

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterBooking.MyHolder>
```

Comment: Did you extend your adapter properly ? as AdapterBooking.Holder?

Comment: So you say it's working on emulator. But not on physical device. What output is your logcat showing when you try to see it on device?

Comment: Its returning an empty data somehow in my AsyncClass

Comment: Where is that url hosted? Are you sure the server is up and running ?

Comment: Its hosted on ultidev and its running. This is the response i get I/System.out: Response: 200
I/System.out: []

Answer (score 0):

Check your Layout, make sure your RecyclerView isn't child of ScrollView. If you need that, you can use NestedScrollView.

If you make a breakpoint, your onBindViewHolder works?

Another thing yo can try:

There is a RecyclerView method: setHasStableIds(boolean).

```
@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    return false;
}
```

Also, I think the context is wrong:

In activity:

```
private Activity getActivity {
    return this;
}
```

In AsyncTask:

```
mAdapter = new AdapterBooking(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),data);
```

I hope this information help you.

Good luck.

Comment: No luck no changes

Comment: And... Inflating the view as follow:
view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Im using shared preference to store data so I used the wrong key to get a value from the shared preference which before was causing the sharedpreference value to be initialized to zero.